# Transaction without locking whole table ef core c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am trying to get an use the database context to begin a transaction. Im getting the result i needed but the problem is that when i start the transaction, the tables affected by the transaction get locked. I am adding new data to the tables and i wish for only the new rows to be locked until the transaction completes instead of the whole table. Is this achievable in entity framework core c# transactions?

Comment: You can specify an isolation level, see also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/transactions

Comment: i've tried read uncommitted, repeatableread, chaos

Comment: all of them just lock the table i am adding new rows to

Comment: i've tried all isolation levels. except serializable ofc. They lock the complete table

Comment: You can use snapshot isolation on your reads.

Comment: tried that . didn't work. I ran the sql command that enables snapshot isolation level on the database using this statement

ALTER DATABASE <db name> SET ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION ON

then set the transaction scope to Snapshot

.didn't have much effect

Comment: Reading data isn't the problem. i have read uncommitted on all my related reads. The problem im facing is that i need to add rows at the same time too. Like using two transactions to add unique rows into the same tables at the same time

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood you then. What is the problem you experience, are you getting timeouts, deadlocks, other? How have you concluded that the table is locked? Could you also show your schema including indexes if any.

Comment: And also... I don't get any notifications of your messages, unless you mention me :)

Comment: I'm getting timeouts due to the locks. If i start one transaction that is supposed to add some new rows to a table and start another transaction that is to add some new records which are different from the ones added by the first transaction in the same table,  the second one doesn't add its entries until the first transaction completes. whereas the case should be that they should simultaneously add rows to the same table.- @asgerhallas